# AWS lambda to create ec2 instance using Launch template and boto3 only using the required permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, boto3

I am having problems setting the correct permissions to my IAM role that is assumed by a lambda function. The purpose of the lambda is to launch ec2 instance using the provided Launch Template. However, I am constantly getting `You are not authorized to perform this operation.`errors due to not correct permissions of the IAM role.

The only policy I am attaching at the moment to the role is this one:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:RunInstances",
                "ec2:GetLaunchTemplateData"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Lambda boto3/python code:

```
import boto3

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')

lt = {
    # 'LaunchTemplateId': 'lt-0b91c7e5c5437a1c1',
    'LaunchTemplateName': 'template_name',
    'Version': '$Latest'
}


def handler(event, context):

    instances = ec2.create_instances(
        LaunchTemplate=lt,
        MinCount=1,
        MaxCount=1
        # UserData=user_data
    )
```

**Note**: If I attach `AmazonEC2FullAccess` AWS Managed policy to the lambda role it works fine

What am I missing?

Also, is there an easy way of finding what are the "bare minimum" IAM policy permissions that are needed by a resource to function?

Comment: Depends what your instance does.  Does it use instance role, or keypairs? All the extra things have their own permissions.

Comment: The launched EC2 instance does not have any roles attached to it (i.e. the Launch Template I am using doesn't have Launch Profile attached to it). 

The Launch Template does have a keypair attached to it as well. Could that be it?

Comment: @Marcin I had a look at my Launch Template and it did set a few tags on the launched instances from the template. So after modifying the above role to include the `CreateTags` action it worked fine. Thank you so much! I was not aware that the permissions should cover all of the resources that are created by the Launch Template as well. Lesson learned :)

Comment: Glad it worked out. If you don't mind, I will provide an answer for future reference.

Comment: Yes, please. That would be great :) Thank you again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

Often, `RunInstances` permission is not enough to launch an instance. What permissions are required depends on what does the instance do, e.g. uses KMS encrypted volumes, iam instance roles/profiles, set tags and more.

In the OPs case, the instance to be launched was using tags, thus `ec2:CreateTags` permission was needed to make it work.